# How do I manage alerts for a blog on SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, blog

I'm able to find where I can add alerts for blogs by going to Blog > Categories > Edit however, this doesn't allow me to manage already existing alerts.

For a normal site I can just go into Site Actions and manage them but this option isn't visible on blogs so I'm not sure how to manage the alerts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### End User

Setting up an alert for blog posts is a bit hidden.

Without a shortcut, the easiest steps I can find to setup a new alert are:

1. Click a blog post
2. Click "Posts" in the breadcrumb
3. Click Actions -> Alert Me

### Site Administrator

To manage existing alerts, make sure you are within the site that contains the blog. For example, if your Posts list is at `http://server/Site/News/All/Lists/Posts/AllPosts.aspx` then the site is `http://server/Site/News/All`

Then, click Site Actions -> Site Settings -> User alerts. The URL will be similar to: `http://server/Site/News/All/_layouts/sitesubs.aspx`.

---

To create a shortcut for users, simply create a link to the alerts page on the Posts list. The easiest way to get this link is by following the "End User" steps above. It'll look something like: `http://server/Site/News/All/_layouts/SubNew.aspx?List=%7B37D342E1%2D3E21%2D48BD%2DADF4%2D96FD675B37AE%7D&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fserver%2FSite%2FNews%2FAll%2FLists%2FPosts%2FAllPosts.aspx`

You can change the Source URL parameter to link back to your main page.

Comment: There are powershell methods for accessing alerts too, but probably rare you would need to use those.